# How can I save an association returned from a fineOne with sequelize.js?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have:

```
        let foundConversation = await req.db.models.Conversation.findOne({
            where: {
                id: ConversationId
            },
            include: [{
                model: req.db.models.Audio
            }]
        })
```

This returns a `Conversation` and an `Audio` attached to that conversation.

When I do:

```
foundConversation.Audio.processingData.stuff = requestObj
await foundConversation.Audio.save()
```

it doesn't save the `Audio` data. Is there any way for me to do this?

I'd rather not do a separate class `.update` since I want `foundConversation` to continue to have the updated `Audio` data for further processing.

Update, my associations:

```
    Models.audio.belongsTo(Models.conversation, {
        allowNull: true,
        onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    })

    Models.conversation.hasOne(Models.audio)
```

Comment: Can you add the model definitions also to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could tell better if you share the model definitions too..

It could be one of the two issues:

1. There is no `foundConversation.Audio`. Maybe because of incorrect name you used `Models.audio` and `models.Conversation` Notice different in capitalisation.
2. `foundConversation.Audio.processingData.stuff` This indicates you are trying to change a property within a property of a model.. Are you using JSON Columns?

Also i noticed you are injecting db in express request (via a middleware) `req.db.models`. Ideally it should not be a property of request and should be accessed via a service: `dbService.models`